# OData Iqueryable Count or Inline count current rules?

Tags: count, odata, asp.net-web-api, iqueryable

I am finding old code and examples of trying to get a count of our records back to show up. What is the newest acceptable way? I see old things where people say it is not supported yet (2013), and others where people are overriding things, I see apicontroller and OdataController.

I have google searched and such, and it scatters throughout the years..I am wondering what is the current best practice for webapi's to do counts.